# this.func() fails in Jest/Jasmine test

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jestjs

Ahh! Why does `node fooey.js` work fine when run on the NodeJS command line, but fails when run from Jest/Jasmine?

Jest/Jasmine ERROR:

   `it foo() returns a string.
     - TypeError: this.bar is not a function`

If I use the commented out lines below for `self = this` and `self.bar()` the tests pass OK.

fooey.js

```
var Fooey = function() {
    // var self = this;

    this.foo = function(phrase) {
        var result = this.bar(phrase); 
        // var result = self.bar(phrase);

        return result;
    };

    this.bar = function(greeting) {
        var result = greeting + " Watz up?"

        console.log(result);

        return result;
    };
};


module.exports = Fooey;

var fooey = new Fooey();

fooey.foo("Hi Bob!");
fooey.bar("Yo Carl!");
```

fooey-test.js

```
jest.unmock('../fooey'); // unmock to use the actual implementation.

describe('foo()', () => {

   const Fooey = require('../fooey');
   const fooey = new Fooey();

   const foo = fooey.foo;
   const bar = fooey.bar;


   it('foo() returns a string.', () => {

      var result = foo("Hi Bob!");

      expect(typeof result).toBe('string');
   });
});
```

Comment: The problem is precisely because of the difference in ***how you're calling `foo()`.*** Nothing specific to Jasmine.

Comment: @deceze Can you be more specific, I can't see what you see -)

Comment: `fooey.foo()` !== `foo()`. Read the duplicate *how the `this` keyword works*.

Comment: OK, I got my Jest test working using `fooey.foo("Hi Bob!")` instead of `foo("Hi Bob!")`. Thanks, I'll read up more on `this`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work